# Excel find Median from non contiguous cells and ignore 0 values

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, median, google-sheets-formula

I've got a complex Excel sheet and want to find median on different cells which are scattered for example **A1, C1, G1, X1, Z1 etc.** and want to Ignore Cells having 0 values so that these 0s cant be counted in `median`, any idea how I can do it?

The following function can do this But the problem is: it counts 0 as well, is there any way to modify this formula to ignore 0s

```
MEDIAN(A1,C1,G1,X1,Z1)
```

Comment: If you read the values from the spreadsheet into an array, say, `arr = [3, 0, 5, 7, 0, -1]`, simply calculate the median from the values in the array `a = arr - [0] #=> [3, 5, 7, -1]`. Depending on how you define the median, that might be `half = a.size/2 #=> 2; a.size.odd? ? a[half] : (a[half-1]+a[half]).fdiv(2) #=> 6.0`.

Comment: @carySwoveland that should be the logic but How i can make this happen within Excel ?

Comment: In the definition I know, for @CarySwoveland's idea you want to sort the zeroless array first. The median for 3, 5, 7, and -1 ought to be 4, since -1, 3, 5, 7 has 3 and 5 as the middle numbers.

Comment: I see I forgot to sort in computing the array `a` in my earlier comment. That should of course be `a = (array-[0]).sort`. @Jeremy, thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on Google sheets, and I imagine it should work on Excel. The median function ignores blank cells. So you just need to make the 0s empty. An IF can be used for that. Suppose we know column AA is empty. Then where your formula says MEDIAN(A1, we would need to say `MEDIAN(if(A1=0,AA1,A1),`. Proceeding similarly for C1, G1, X1, and Z1 will give you the formula you need.
Note it would be nice if in place of AA1 we could just say "", but that causes an error.

REVISION: I'm adding some new ideas and clarification, based on helpful comments.
The original idea led to the formula:

```
=MEDIAN(if(A1=0,AA1,A1),if(C1=0,AA1,C1),if(G1=0,AA1,G1),if(X1=0,AA1,X1),if(Z1=0,AA1,Z1))
```

Chronocidal proposed the following improvement, which works nicely, is more compact, and does not depend on some empty cell that has no relevance.

```
=MEDIAN(if(A1<>0,A1),if(C1<>0,C1),if(G1<>0,G1),if(X1<>0,X1),if(Z1<>0,Z1))
```

Comment: as i understand i need to add IF condition for each cell and if 0 ignore that cell and find median on rest of the cells - is this correct ? in my case, there might be lot of cells and adding IF for each cell, will be a lot.

Comment: or may i see this google doc to understand how you are doing this ?

Comment: Try inverting the `IF` and dropping the third argument entirely?  `MEDIAN(If(A1<>0,A1))` ?

Comment: The formula ends up =MEDIAN(if(A1=0,AA1,A1),if(C1=0,AA1,C1),if(G1=0,AA1,G1),if(X1=0,AA1,X1),if(Z1=0,AA1,Z1)) I could share the sheet, but you would not see much. @Chronocidal the inversion gave me a formula parse error, but it was a good idea.

Comment: @Chronocidal I'm sorry, I typed that in wrong. Yes, that seems to work, thank you.

Comment: @JeremyKahan i dont think this is ignoring 0s in excel. i cant get this working in excel

Comment: @Chronocidal it works fine in Google sheet but doesn't work in excel

Comment: I tried the original version =MEDIAN(if(A1=0,AA1,A1),if(C1=0,AA1,C1),if(G1=0,AA1,G1),if(X1=0,AA1,X1),if(Z1=0,AA1,Z1)) in Excel on my machine, and it was working. The improved one appears not to. Also, array formulas do exist in Excel, but they are implemented differently.

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple **`AVERAGE`** to solve this:

```
=AVERAGE(A1, C1, G1, X1, Z1)
```

where empty values are not counted

---

for ignoring 0's you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(IF({A1, C1, G1, X1, Z1}>0, {A1, C1, G1, X1, Z1}, )))
```

or if you want **`MEDIAN`**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MEDIAN(IF({A1, C1, G1, X1, Z1}>0, {A1, C1, G1, X1, Z1}, )))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: it works well in Google Sheet but i can not get this working in excel. this is how I'm trying in excel:


  `{=MEDIAN(IF((A1, C1, G1, X1, Z1)>0, (A1, C1, G1, X1, Z1), )))}`

I'm not very expert in excel, I would really appreciate if you can guide me how i can do it in excel. thanks

Comment: sry, no idea how to do this in Excel

Comment: No issue - Thanks. I'm doing some research in excel if i can get this working in excel